# What is difference between “real-world object” , surface, AR anchors?

Tags: arkit

I am looking for a technical answer to the question :

What is difference between “real-world object” , surface, AR anchors in ARkit?

I believe and as for as I can tell:
1) ARkit offers 3 different methods to search for “real-world objects” , surfaces , AR Anchors.

- ARSCNView hitTest(_:types:)
  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnview/2875544-hittest
- ARSKView hitTest(_:types:)
  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arskview/2875733-hittest
- ARFrame hitTest(_:types:)
  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2875718-hittest

I understand to look for SceneKit /SpriteKit content displayed in the view you need to use different hitTest methods.

I just can’t understand what is “real-world object” is vs surface vs AR anchor?

My best guess is:

Real-world object:
- I don’t know?
Surface: 
- featurePoints
- estimatedHorizontalPlane
-estimatedVerticalPlane
AR anchors:
ARImageAnchor
ARFaceAnchor
ARPlaneAnchor

I think you get the idea.... what is a “real-world object” in ARKit?

Any help would be great. The documentation seem to really  emphasize the difference between “real-works object or surface”.

Thank you
Smartdog
We all learn by sharing what we know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My intuition is that whoever wrote Apple’s docs kept things ambiguous because a) you can use those methods for multiple kinds of hit tests, and b) ARKit doesn’t *really* know what it’s looking at.

If you do a hit test for any of the plane-related types (`existingPlane`, `estimatedHorizontalPlane`, etc), you’re looking for real-world flat surfaces. Or rather, you’re looking for things that ARKit “thinks” look like flat horizontal (or vertical, in iOS 11.3 and later) surfaces. Those might or might not accurately reflect the shape of the real world at any given moment, but they’re ARKit’s best guess. Which of the plane-related types you search for determines whether you get an existing `ARAnchor`.

(Note false negatives are more common than false positives. For example, you might find no hit result at a point where a corner of tabletop hasn’t been mapped by ARKit, but you’re unlikely to find a plane hit result with no corresponding real-world flat surface.)

If you do a `featurePoint` hit test, you’re testing against ARKit’s sparse map of the user’s environment. If you turn on the `showFeaturePoints` option in `ARSCNView` you can see this map — in each frame of video, it finds tens to small-hundreds of points that are visually interesting enough (well, “interesting” from a particular algorithm’s point of view) that it can correlate their 2D positions between frames and use parallax differences to estimate their distances from the camera and positions in 3D space. (In turn, that informs ARKit’s idea of where the device itself is in 3D space.)

Because a “feature point” can be any small, high-contrast region in the camera image, it doesn’t really correlate to any specific kind of real-world thing. If you’re looking at a desk with a nice wood-grain pattern, you’ll see a lot of feature points along the plane of the desktop. If you’re looking at a desk with, say, a potted plant on it, you’ll see some points on the desktop and some on the pot and some on the leaves... not enough points that you (or a CV algorithm) can really intuit the shape of the plant. But enough that, if the user were to tap on one of those points, your app could put some 3D object there and it might convincingly appear to stick to the plant.

So, in the most general sense, ARKit hit testing is looking for “objects” of some sort in the “real world” (as perceived by ARKit), but unless you’re looking for planes (surfaces) one can’t really be more specific about what the “objects” might be.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer this question.
@rickster you stated:
<h1>My intuition is that whoever wrote Apple’s docs kept things ambiguous because a) you can use those methods for multiple kinds of hit tests, and b) ARKit doesn’t really know what it’s looking at.</h1>

I felt the same way and the reason I ask the question :-)

thank you the clear analysis of the issue.

Comment: adding to my comment from above:
@rickster you stated:
<h1>So, in the most general sense, ARKit hit testing is looking for “objects” of some sort in the “real world” (as perceived by ARKit), but unless you’re looking for planes (surfaces) one can’t really be more specific about what the “objects” might be.</h1>

This is exactly the same conclusion I have come to also.

Maybe Apple has something up their sleeve :-))

Smartdog
We all learn by sharing what we know.